# How to add a point on the opposite edge at 90 degrees

Tags: vertices, edges, intersection

How to add a point perpendicular to the selected one on the opposite edge?

[image]

Comment: use this great free included addon in preferences; Mesh: Snap_Utilities_Line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technique that works if the two edges are parallel to a world axis:

- go to edge select mode (Shortcut <kbd>2</kbd> *on the keyboard, not keypad*) and select the edge you want the new vertex on.
- right click and select *subdivide* from the popup.
- got to vertex select mode (Shortcut <kbd>1</kbd> *on the keyboard, not keypad*) and select the original point.
- Open the side panel if it's not already open (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>)
- hover over the correct axis value, in your case `Y` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the coordinate value.
- Select the new point (created by the subdivide)
  hover over the correct axis value, in your case `Y` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the coordinate value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a tricky shape as shown below. Select the vertex that serves as reference to an intersecting point on the opposite side when perpendicularly extending an edge from the reference vertex edge.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*
- Set [`Transform Pivot Point`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html) to *3D Cursor*
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> the other 2 vertices on the same edge to include them in your selection
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the line
- <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it into a long edge and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
- Press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to rotate line 90 degrees on z-axis
- Go to *Active Tool and Workspace Settings* and tick *Auto Merge* and *Split Edges & Faces*
- Hover over your object and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Notice how you have interesected an edge on the opposite side and created a new vertex. Now you can delete the excess edge and the other vertices of the line since they are not more needed.

[image]

You can also use use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> on a vertex to move it along the edge. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to extend it along that line until it intersects the opposite side.

[image]